# Gimp color picker is wrong

Tags: gimp

I'm new to Gimp and it seems the color picker does take a color brighter than it is supposed, i have to get the hexa color from another app using screenshot.

is there any settings that will make it work properly?

Comment: A useful approach for such questions would be to have a look at the issue tracker for GIMP: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=color+picker - it's public and searchable; most Free Software has trackers like these and the comments there also provide source material for complete and factually sound answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot does not carry the same RGB numbers than your application, from where the screenshot was taken. The screenshots have got all enhancements and color corrections that your operating system and display graphics card are programmed to insert.

An example: I have got very colorful and sweeet monitor with wide color reproduction range. It shows all colors more saturated than other monitors with the same input signal.

That's nice for entertainment, but to edit photos I must have a screen calibration program (=Spyder) ON. It has measured my screen. Everything visible is recalculated to compensate the exaggeration in the screen. The screenshots unfortunately contain that correction and look out grey and dull elsewhere and also when imported to a photo editor in my system.

To make the screenshots closer to the thing that an application tries to display you must switch all color enhancements off and let your system to work like you had a standard sRGB monitor. How to do that - I cannot say, that's a system adminstration problem.

Comment: I have noticed the color picker inside the color selection panel works wrong, but the color picker tool works just fine.